# How do I upgrade this light fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I would like to improve the lighting in the living room but found that the fixture for the ceiling fan is inadequate (two E-12 bases).
I was looking into replacing it but it seems more complicated than I thought -- I don't know how to find something that is compatible with this fan as all the universal ones work with the fans with a switch cap and center hole. There is also no obvious model number or anything on the fan either. Any idea on where I can start?
[image: Whole ceiling fan]

[image: Wiring]

Comment: There are solutions.  Can you add pictures of the bottom side of the light panel (the white part with the bulb sockets), add the diameter of that part, and also add a pic of the glass shade?  There are solutions.  Look at "Ceiling fan LED light engine" and at ultra-bright LED bulbs.  EG rather than a "40 watt equivalent" (which is actually about 6W) you can get an *actual* 25W LED bulb with an E12 base, or an *actual* 40W light engine.  They are amazing.

Comment: You've tried the highest-wattage LED bulb you can fit in there, e.g. 100W (maybe even 150W) equivalent?  As @jay613 suggests, lamps are rated for incandescent bulbs, and nearly all LED bulbs of reasonable size will easily fit under that wattage rating.  Example: the typical 100W-equivalent LED bulb is about 14W.

Comment: It has been my experience that the light kit cannot be replaced, even with one from the same manufacturer. I've installed a number of ceiling fans in my house over the last 30 years, and it seems that they change the mounting method, housing size, etc. every couple of years to prevent you from putting a new light kit on an old fan. IMHO, it's done intentionally to make you buy more product, much like cell phone manufacturers used to change the charging plug on every new model to force you to buy all new chargers with each new phone.

Comment: Interesting, @jay613. I'd never heard of a "light engine". Someone got smart and started selling complete LED/driver replacements for all-in-one LED fixtures.

Comment: @jay613 Interesting indeed... I'll measure it when I get home, I just know the whole enclosure is about 7" diameter so the bottom part should be about the same. Light engine seems like a good option, worried about overheating inside the shade though. Glass shade is even larger -- will add pics soon.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to upgrade a ceiling fan's light fixture to produce a lot more light is with an "LED Light Engine".   These are relatively new (in 2023) purpose-made discs of LEDs that fit inside a (usually) round light fixture and replace not just the old bulbs but also their sockets and some of their wiring.

**Installation** They are easy to install, but require a little bit of electrical knowledge.  Physically they either install on the fixtures threaded rod if it has one, or by magnets or mounting screws onto the fixture body otherwise.  Depending on the fixture you might need to remove the old light sockets and their wiring.  Pay attention to cooling.  Most light engines are mounted on metal plates that face upwards.  If your fixture has insulation at the top don't butt the metal place up against it.  Install it in a way that lets air circulate.    If you have a fixture that has a threaded rod that's easy, otherwise I'm not sure (because mine do).

**Performance** Three 40 watt incandescent bulbs might produce 1200 lumens altogether.  A single 9 inch 40W LED light engine might produce 3600 lumens.  The light is fantastic.

**Heat** The LED device produces a lot less heat than the incandescent bulbs that it replaces.   However, in a closed light fixture (the glass bowl is pressed tight to the fixture body) the heat might cause premature failure of the device.    In my opinion, it's well worth it.   They are supposed to last for years, but if they fail after 12 or 18 months the additional light and low cost make them an easy buy for me.

**Wait, there's more: Uplight** Some ceiling fans also have "uplights". (But apparently not yours).  An additional fixture above the fan blades that uses several 4W night-light bulbs as ceiling warmers.    Guess what? *This is cool* You can buy LED equivalents that are 3W.  Not 3W equivalent.  3 actual watts.  300 lumens each.   If your fan has 6 of these that's another 1800 lumens.  Your ceiling warmers now produce more light than the entire fixture with up and down lights did before.   If you buy 2700K bulbs for this, and a 4000K (or whatever you like) light engine, you can mix them with the dimmers for nice effects.

**Tips**

- When replacing the globe, don't tighten it hard to the fixture.  Leave a small gap to let heat escape.
- If you light fixture has a threaded rod down the middle, make sure to buy a light engine has a hole for it.  If the light engine doesn't come with an extra nut to fit the rod, buy one ... it's a lot easier to install that way.
- Make sure the entire light engine, including any sticky-outy mounting ears, will fit through the **neck** of your lamp shade.    Note, a "7 inch light engine" might be 8 to 10 inches across at its widest part, depending on its design.  And what appears to be a huge lamp shade might be 8 or 9 inches at its neck. Measure.
- Make sure to buy a dimmable light engine if your fan fixture has a dimmer.